# dca: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel?

Tags: linux

When I insert the `dca` module in `rcS`, I will see the following error when using `dmesg`. I saw online that it was caused by the inconsistency between the versions of `bzImage` and `dca.ko`, but my `bzImage` and `dca.ko` were compiled simultaneously, and when I manually executed `insmod dca.ko` in the terminal window, I used `dmesg` to check, but there was no error. What is the problem? Is it because the timing of loading in `rcS` is incorrect?

error in `dmesg`:

```
[    5.889617] dca: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    5.889946] dca service started, version 1.12.1
```

`insmod` in `rcS`:

```
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/dca.ko
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/i2c-algo-bit.ko
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/pps_core.ko
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/ptp.ko
insmod /lib/modules/6.4.0-rt8/igb.ko
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your other kernel modules are *signed* - perhaps with a key that was auto-generated by the kernel build process, if you haven't chosen otherwise.

Your `dca.ko` is not signed - or at least, not with the same key.

If Secure Boot is not in use, the kernel will start by trusting only the key it was built with, but has the option of accepting non-verifiable kernel modules while marking the kernel as tainted on loading such a module.

With Secure Boot in effect, the Secure Boot signing keys and the Machine Owner's Key (MOK) maintained by the `shimx64.efi` are normally added to the list of keys trusted by the kernel, in addition to the axiomatically trusted key the kernel was built with, but then the kernel *should* be also configured to reject attempts to load non-verifiable kernel modules - otherwise it would not be fully Secure Boot-compliant.

(When building your own kernels, you obviously can decide exactly how strictly Secure Boot-compliant you want to be - but if you distribute kernels that can run under Secure Boot but accept non-verifiable modules, such kernels can be blacklisted as "Secure Boot circumvention devices" and rejected by future Secure Boot-aware system firmware versions.)

For more details, see [Documentation/admin-guide/module-signing.rst](https://mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/admin-guide/module-signing.rst) in the kernel source code package.

To get rid of the taint message, you could sign the `dca.ko` module using the `scripts/sign-file` tool in the kernel source code tree, and the private key specified by the `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_KEY` build-time option (or if unset, the default autogenerated key at `certs/signing_key.pem` in the kernel source tree). The hash algorithm used in signing the kernel modules is specified by the `CONFIG_MODULE_SIG_HASH` build-time option.